# Validator in java for timestamp

Tags: java, spring-boot, datetime

Is their inbuilt annotation for validating Date time format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS`
I have a request object in Spring boot with input as
`2019-01-01 02:23:28.001`. I need to validate at request time only by adding custom validator or inbuilt validator that format of my request is correct or not.

Comment: A Date doesn't have any format. A String has, so if your bean property is a String, you can use the Pattern annotation.

Comment: @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "MM/dd/yyyy")
I dont want to use this.
I want to write custom validator for this.
Do you have any code related to custom validator.

Comment: Read my comment again. A validator validates the properties of a bean. Your bean property is (I guess) of type Date. A Date doesn't have any format: it's just a number of milliseconds since the epoch. So validating the format of a Date doesn't make sense: when the validator is called, the JSON string has already been parsed to a Date.

Answer (score 0):

```
This worked for me:

@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = DateTimeFormatValidator.class)
public @interface ValidDateTimeFormat {
    String message() default "Date Format is not valid.";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}


public class DateTimeFormatValidator
    implements ConstraintValidator<ValidDateTimeFormat, String> {
    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
        sdf.setLenient(false);
        try {
            sdf.parse(value);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`.